# Xarray : Extract a different subdomain at each time step from dataset

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

I'm working with the following surface pressure dataset, MSLP_ds :
`<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 85, nj: 1602, ni: 1602)
Coordinates:
latitude   (nj, ni) float64 ...
longitude  (nj, ni) float64 ...

- ni         (ni) float64 9.086e+05 9.089e+05 ... 1.309e+06 1.309e+06
- nj         (nj) float64 9.086e+05 9.089e+05 ... 1.309e+06 1.309e+06
- time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-12-22T01:00:00 ... 2018-12-23T23:30:00
  Data variables:
  MSLP       (time, nj, ni) float64 ...
  Attributes:
  nco_openmp_thread_number:   1
  history:                    Wed Jul 12 13:38:25 2023: ncks -A -v MSLP CI2...
  history_of_appended_files:  Wed Jul 12 13:38:25 2023: Appended file CI250...
  NCO:                        "4.6.2"`

where MSLP is the surface pressure.
I'm not interested in the whole domain and would like to extract a square subdomain from this dataset, but this subdomain is different at each time step.
This sub-domain is defined by 4 numpy arrays that contain indices for each time step of the corner of the sub-domain I want to extract:
indi_w, indi_e , indj_s , indj_n
with a size equivalent to the time coordinate.

So far, I'm able to extract the same subdomain for all time steps using :

```
tt=70
MSLP_ds_sub = MSLP_ds['MSLP'].isel(nj=slice(indj_s[tt],indj_n[tt]),ni=slice(indi_w[tt],indi_e[tt]))
```

But I can't figure out how to associate a different sub-domain with each time step, so I've tried

```
MSLP_ds_mod = MSLP_ds['MSLP'].isel(nj=slice(indj_s,indj_n),ni=slice(indi_w,indi_e) )
```

thinking that for each time step a different index would be used but of course I got an error because I passed an array instead of a scalar for an index... :
`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

My question is:
Can a different subdomain be extracted from a datarray for each time step (knowing the indices to define the subdomain) without using a loop over the time step?
Any suggestions would be most welcome!
Thank you very much!